# Realm Notifications for Changes to Child Objects

Tags: swift, realm

I have a list of `Entry` items and each one has associated tasks. These entries are populated in a `UITableView` like this:

[image]

The blue pill () shows the number of tasks for each entry. Here are my class definitions in Realm:

```
class Entry: NSObject{
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  ...
}
class Task: NSObject{
  @objc dynamic var entry: Entry?
  ...
}
```

My goal is to monitor Realm notifications to update the task count on each entry **without reloading the whole** `UITableView`. I'm currently doing this by putting a Realm notification listener on each and every `UITableViewCell` like this:

```
//---------- UITableView delegate ----------
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let entry = entries[indexPath.row]
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EntryCell", for: indexPath) as! EntryCell

  cell.label.text = entry.name

  //Task count
  cell.entry = entry
  cell.setupRealmListener()

  return cell    
}

//---------- Table Cell Definition ----------
class EntryCell: UITableViewCell{
  @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var date: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var taskCount: UILabel!
  var entry: Entry!

  //Task Count
  func setupRealmListener(){    
    let realm = try! Realm()
    guard !realm.isInWriteTransaction else{ return }
    //***
    token = realm.observe{ notification, realm in
      let tasks = realm.objects(Task.self).filter("entry = %@", self.entry)
      taskCount.text = "\(tasks.count)"
    }
  }

  deinit {
    token?.invalidate()
  }
}
```

There are a few reasons why I've gone this route, but I'm wondering if there's a better way:

1. I have a notification for when my `entries` collection changes,
   but that doesn't fire when a task gets added/changed.
2. I use a realm notification on the `EntryCell` but that feels like a lot of resources hanging on a single table cell.

I'm getting tons of warnings from Realm because I have a notification on my `UITableViewCell` and as it is `dequeue`'d, it doesn't seem to be `deinit`'d:

> *RLMNotificationToken released without unregistering a notification. You must hold on to the RLMNotificationToken returned from addNotificationBlock and call -[RLMNotificationToken invalidate] when you no longer wish to receive RLMRealm notifications.*

Any ideas on a better way to update the task count on each entry individually without reloading the whole table?

Comment: Why don't you use https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collection-notifications ? You don't have to reload the whole table, and you don't have to add observer in a cell.

Comment: @AchmadJP Because an `Entry` collection notification won't fire when a `Task` object is changed.

Comment: I read that `Entry` has associated `Task`s, so I thought that `Entry` has list of `Task` in their object. I'm thinking of another solution which move listener to a dedicated worker, and have this worker tell the table view which index need to update, if the cell is shown, than you call a specific function to update the blue pill

Comment: I know you found a solution but.... there's probably an overall better approach. Best practice is to leverage MVC (Mode, View, Controller) - the model would be your Realm objects, the View is the UI and the controller is what controls/connects the models to the views. So what should be happening is the *controller* should be observing your realm data (not the cell) and updating the datasource when there's change and then update *that row in your tableViewUI*. It's not a good idea to add observers etc in cells as they can go out of scope and crash, as you've discovered.

Comment: Also, the code in the question is a bit incomplete; is *entries* a Results collection? If I am reading it correctly, Entry objects have a number of Tasks that go with each?  Why aren't the Tasks objects contained within a List property of an Entry? If you do that, whenever a task is added it *will* fire an event and then you'll know which entry it was, can get the new count and update the UI. It would be a much cleaner, more maintainable and simpler approach. It would also significantly reduce the number of observers. However I could be reading it incorrectly.

Comment: @Jay I've given this a lot of thought and am going to try going with what you've described. I've known about having a child `List<Task>` property on my `Entry` class, but didn't like the idea of managing them through my entries. But I'll give it a shot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found a good solution for this. I know I could have added a list of `tasks` to my `Entry` schema, but I've never liked managing lists. I seem to get more crashes because of invalidated/deleted objects and such and I'm constantly worried the order will get messed up somehow.

Instead, when I add or remove a `task`, I just update a timestamp on my `entry` object so that its notifications fire:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
realm.beginWrite()

//Update the task
task.name = "New stuff here..."

//Ping the entry so its notifications fire
if let entry = task.entry{
  entry.updated = Date()
}

try! realm.commitWrite()
```

It's a pretty simple technique and seems to meet my needs. Now I can remove the per-entry notification on my table cell.

Comment: *because of invalidated/deleted objects* That's happening because the observers are within the tableView cells which is not a good place as they can go out of scope, be re-created etc by the OS.